# WiX setup: How to display language-dependant license file

Tags: localization, wix

I am creating a WiX setup which should be available in two languages (two msi-files: one for de-de and one for en-us).
In the setup the `WixUI_InstallDir` is used, i.e. before selecting the installation directory the license is displayed.
I would like to display the license in the language for which the setup was created.

In my setup project the license files are located under

```
Localization\de-de\Softwarelizenzbestimmungen.rtf
```

and

```
Localization\en-us\License Agreement.rtf
```

To display the license during setup, I need to set the Wix variable `"WixUILicenseRtf"` to the appropriate value.

I tried the following:

In the localization files I added:

```
de-en.wxl:
<String Id="LicenseFile">Localization\de-de\Softwarelizenzbestimmungen.rtf</string>
```

```
en-us.wxl:
<String Id="LicenseFile">Localization\en-us\Licence Agreement.rtf</string>
```

And in Product.wxs:

```
<WixVariable Id="WixUILicenseRtf" Value="!(loc.LicenseFile)" />.
```

But this returns the (compile time) error:
"The system cannot find the file '!(loc.LicenseFile)'."

I know that the Property `ProductLanguage` contains the setup language, or at least the LCID from which I can derive the language.

So I tried this:

```
<?if ProductLanguage = '1031' ?>
  <WixVariable Id="WixUILicenseRtf" Value="Localization\de-de\Softwarelizenzbestimmungen.rtf" />
<?else ?>
  <WixVariable Id="WixUILicenseRtf" Value="Localization\en-us\Licence Agreement.rtf" />
<?endif ?>
```

Also without success: The English license agreement (else-branch) is always displayed.

CustomActions to set properties are of no use to me either, because they are executed during the InstallSequence.

So how can I build my setup so that the English setup displays the "License Agreement.rtf" file contents and the German setup displays the "Softwarelizenzbestimmungen.rtf" file contents?

Answer (score 0):

Have you referenced your localization files in your call to light.exe using the -loc argument?

light myfile.wixobj -loc de-de.wxl